# Context free grammar for the language {a^{i}b^{j}, j> 2i}

Tags: context-free-grammar

I tried to do it by myself and got this answer but this way of deducing the answer doesn't seem to match anyone's answer on the internet.

$$S \rightarrow aSbbB$$

$$B \rightarrow bB|\epsilon$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: Things to check: (1) can the S ever go away? (2) are you handling the edge cases properly (e.g., $i=0$ or $j=2i$)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're missing something.  Actually two things.  First, if every instance of $B$ is chosen as $\epsilon$, you're left with a case where $j=2i$ rather than $j>2i$.  Second, Every $S$ in your grammar contains another $S$ so it only produces infinite strings.

Comment: S--> aSbbB|e

B--> bB|e where e means epsilon   . Is tis correct?

Comment: Sorry, I gave a bad hint.  To reiterate, you still need to fix the situation where $j=2i$ and you need to make sure your grammar doesn't accept the empty string.  Your answer is really close, except that the second option for $S$ is a little bit off.  What can you change it to to address both problems I mentioned?